# Securing S3 Bucket Against Replay Attacks From 3rd Party Uploads

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, architecture

I'm creating a way for clients to upload large files to S3 for us to process.

I built a mechanism that allows clients to send the list of files they have and in return they get an HTTP request they need to send to S3, along with the file attached, for one of the files they offered. This removes the strain of uploads from our server and we can pick up any file that has been uploaded via notification from the S3 bucket.

My problem is with replay attacks. If a certain party asks to send a file and receives the request back, they can replay the same request over and over again, costing us in requests. I don't care about overwriting the file since the `Contents-MD5` header forces the file to be the same file (conflicts notwithstanding). I also don't care about being notified about the file completing upload again.

I thought about generating a policy that only allows uploads with a specific token, which changes every X minutes. Should someone want to replay an attack, they would fail and have to re-request an S3 request from us (which would fail, since the upload already completed beforehand). I'm not sure how much of a best practice it would be to rotate such a token and worried it would also cause lots of legitimate requests that are taking too long to start to fail.

Is there any other mechanism I'm not aware of that should be used in this case?

Comment: i am confused by these two things you mentioned: 'an HTTP request they need to send to S3' and 'removes the strain of uploads from our server'? if someone sent a file as attachment to your server and you uploaded it, how does it free your server from the strain of uploading? am i missing something?

Comment: @ketan we expect a lot of concurrent requests for files in the tens of MB. having them all arrive to the server would mean there would have to be thousands of long-living connections to it. instead we reply quickly with a bit of information, offloading the long-lived connection to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> worried it would also cause lots of legitimate requests that are taking too long to start to fail.

You can dismiss that particular worry, by signing the URLs with a short expiration time.  Authentication and authorization, including signature validation, happens at the beginning of the request.  S3 won't cut an upload or download short because the signature expires in the middle of a long request.

Changing bucket policies programmatically, repeatedly, on the fly is definitely not a best practice.

Note that it is does not appear to be clearly documented, but when S3 denies a request, the (negligible, but still non-zero) per-request charge apparently still applies, so having S3 refuse a redundant overwrite of the same object with identical content is unlikely to be a solution worth achieving.

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense. Since data transfer into S3 costs nothing, any solution at this level would cost the same as no solution at all.